# Would pyramid shape buildings prevent people from falling to their deaths?

Tags: building-design, building-physics

If a building the shape of pyramids slops downwards, wouldn't it minimize the risk of fall from heights, whether intentionally or by accident (like fire/bomb scare), from a balcony or window opening? That is discounting falling in a lift shaft or stairwell? Perhaps Egyptians were smart in that sense?

Comment: If the sides are smooth then no... Also what angle?

Comment: I guess angle depends on height of the building?

Comment: The side angle will be a function of height and the base dimensions.

Comment: Yes, I know. However how severe would be the fall based on the angle? A conventional building is 90 deg drop. however if the lower floors have a platform or balcony, that will break the fall?

Comment: Answer to the first and only question is "Depends on a lot of factors."  Other question marks are on statements like this one?

Comment: The Egyptian pyramids were not apartment buildings.

Comment: When you make something idiot proof, there ai always a bigger idiot.

Comment: If chest high balcony rails and windowsills can't stop people from falling over them, then the nothing will.

Comment: Would you take one of the inner flats with no windows nor openings to the outside?

Comment: Pyramid dwellers are already dead. Can dead people be smart?

Comment: All you would be creating is something people would actually jump off for kicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the [ancient Egyptian pyramids](https://www.wonders-of-the-world.net/Pyramids-of-Egypt/Dimensions-of-the-pyramids-of-Egypt.php) as an example, the slope angle of the sides is greater than 50 degrees. You can also experiment with pyramid dimensions and walls angles using [this website](https://www.blocklayer.com/pyramid-calculator.aspx).

People may not "fall" to their deaths from such pyramids, but they will *slide* to their deaths.

To prevent anyone from sliding to their death from a pyramid the wall angles would need to be less than the angle of sliding, which for most situations would be less than 30 degrees.

Comment: Then you could roll to your death instead.

Comment: @DKNguyen: If the the pyramid was tall enough, most likely.

Comment: Oh then why don't people who ride water slides at theme park slide to their death?

Comment: @Nederealm: water acts as a transporting medium. Before they can hit the bottom of a water slide, the water moves them along to a safer & shallower part of the slide. Without water, people would hit the bottom.